# Lens selection for safari trip

Tags: lens-recommendation, safari

Could you please recommend should I carry all my lenses for a Safari Trip to Kruger Park in South Africa? I have the below lenses with Canon 80D Camera

- Sigma 17-70mm f 2.8 - f4 OS HSM
- Tamron SP 70-200mm f2.8 VC USD
- Tamron SP 150-600mm f 5- f 6.3 VC USD
- Canon 50mm f 1.8

I am thinking should I carry both Tamrons or just the 150-600 and save up on weight on my shoulders? I am expecting there will be available light during the day to make sure 150-600 can shoot adequately.

Please help / advise should I carry an extra faster lens?

Comment: Are you only going to be shooting during the day, or will the be any twilight shooting?

Comment: Are you only concerned with photographing the wildlife? Or will you want to capture other aspects of your visit as well? Sitting around the campfire after a day in the field? Visiting the local market? Etc.

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safari

Comment: @Michael Clark Yes I would shoot anything and everything as this would be a once in a lifetime trip, for example I will also try to get a decent star trail/ milky way shot and then I even have Capetown in my itieinary where I might get more shots.  So basically I should carry both lenses with me? I will probably cut the 50mm prime as I wouldn't do much portraiture

Comment: The 50mm f/1.8 will fit in one of your spare pair of shoes. Leaving any of your lenses behind means fewer options in terms of what you can and can not shoot. Only you can really answer that *for you*.

Comment: Damn you are one hell of a motivator, I am taking everything I have then, thanks for the guidance all along these few months.

Comment: @MichaelClark Thanks a lot, all your advice turned out to be worthwhile, I had an amazing trip and I got a lot of great Wildlife pictures. I like to thank you for being awesome. You can check my profile on Instagram https://www.instagram.com/amritbharadwaj/

Answer (score 1):

Many of the animals you are trying to see on safari are most active at dawn and dusk. So the fast long lens will be very useful. You are quite likely to set off before sunrise for a morning drive/hike, and return after dark from the evening one. A fast lens is also good around the lodge grounds in the evening.

Whether or not you return to your lodge in between is another matter. Unless you have to carry everything at all times, you can probably leave heavy kit behind in the middle of the day.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and re assurance that it's worth to carry the weight

Comment: I'd try to get my hands on a spare body as well.

Comment: I don't have a spare body but I can try to rent it out over in Africa to use as a backup, good point